# Openlayers 3 performance markers

Tags: javascript, performance, openlayers, openlayers-3

I have an Openlayers3 map with a lot of markers and I would like to handle it more 
efficiently.

I saw there was a cluster method on the last version of Openlayers and I would like 
to use the same thing on the third version :
http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/strategy-cluster.html

Do I have to use vectors ?

Here is my current code :

```
$.getJSON( "http://localhost/folder/address.json", function(data){

     for(var k in data) {

      var companyCity = data[k].city;
      var companyName = data[k].company;
      var companyLocation = data[k].address;
      var companyLat = data[k].lat;
      var companyLng = data[k].lng;
      var companyPosition = transform([companyLng,companyLat]);

       var elt = $('<p title="'+ companyName +': '+ companyLocation +', '+ companyCity +'"></p>').css({

        "width": '5px',
        "height": '5px',
        "border-radius": '50%',
        "background-color": '#E64411',
        "opacity" : '.5'

       });



       var marker = new ol.Overlay({
        map: map,
        position: companyPosition,
        element: elt
       });


    }
  });
```

Someone has already done it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this post is old but there is a [Clustering example](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/cluster.html) now.

Answer (score 1):

The cluster strategy does rely on having the markers added to a layer.  Is there a strong reason not to do this?  If you were able to have the address.json stored as geoJSON, it is far more "automatic" to use a layer.

If there are strong reasons to not use a layer, you could grab the filter strategy code and customize it to work without a layer.  Looking at [OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster on GitHub](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Strategy/Cluster.js), it looks like you would simply need to manually set features to the array of features you have created and then call cluster() at appropriate times.

Answer (score 0):

As of of 14.11.2013 clustering was not yet available in OpenLayers **3**.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ol3-dev/UDjoZSX3Wx4

Comment: Yes I've seen it. Do you know if it's possible with Google Maps ?